Is there a (unique) way to make a ring with a topology into a topological ring?
Let's say we have a ring with a topology that does is not compatible with the ring operations (so addition or multiplication are not continuous). Is there a natural way to extend the topology to make it into a topological ring? And what if we restrict to the case where either of the operations is already continuous?
You can start by taking every open $U$ and adding $a+U$ and $a^{-1}U$ to the topology and allowing unions and finite intersections. However this only makes the constant addition and mulitplication maps continuous. Which is not enough to make it into a topological ring.
To do this we would need to add opens to $R$ so that the sets $+^{-1}U\subset R\times R$ and $\cdot^{-1}R\subset R\times R$ are open. I don't see what you'd have to do here.
Does anybody have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

You can try to take the intersection $T$ of all such topologies which contain your given one and are compatible with the ring structure. Such topologies exist (e.g. the discrete topology). Try to show that $T$ is again compatible with the ring structure.

Note that any ring can be made into a discrete ring. And the set of topologies of $R$ is partially ordered by  inclusion.

@red_trumpet I'm pretty sure that the intersection of arbitrary ring topologies does not return a ring topology. It seems more possible if the ring topologies form a chain, however here I still get stuck. If this is the case we can use Zorn's lemma to tackle the existence, but I'm not sure about uniqueness

Actually I think uniqueness is not possible. If you take the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ with the cofinite topology, then this is not a topological ring, but taking any $p$-adic topology on $\mathbb{C}$ (topology from the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) gives different topologies extending the cofinite topology

Intersection of  ring topologies will give you the trivial topology. Maybe you want a Hausdorff topology? My suggestion is to work out the case of abelian groups.
